# At what point will Monero forego forced hardforks

Tags: hard-fork, core-development-team

One of bitcoin's greatest strengths is it's resistance to change that is not truly endorsed by the majority. At what point will Monero mimic bitcoin's censorship resistance in the form of truly releasing control to the ecosystem? I anticipate the answer may be complicated.

Comment: hardforks are good for updating the network. despite what bitcoiners will let you to believe hardforks are good. monero schedules hardforks every 6 months right now but there are plans to eventually only have one scheduled hardfork a year. as long as there is a lot of time to prepare there is no reason to fear hardforks

Comment: Thanks for the response. I researched a bit more, listened to fluffy's missive from june '16 and I think I get it now and I like it. It seems to me that some benefits are so it makes people less afraid of hardforks and also appears to encourage participation (specifically through mining right since it's miners that have to signal for the hardfork?)

Comment: and apparently it's meant to make people contribute by breaking things too. nice :)

Comment: ya it makes hardforks an essential part of the evolution of monero. really there is no other way to fully upgrade the network without a hardfork and security updates are critical to have

Comment: For some reason I can't mark your comment as the answer but it definitely answered my question. I'm undecided how I feel about hardforks but I think the monero dev's are taking a scientific approach to the whole thing and maximizing benefit/effect for the monero network.
I understand the need for code changes that are incompatible with previous versions. And I also understand the resiliancy offered by allowing nodes to continue to stick with rules they can agree with. I doubt the bitcoin network would reject a necessary hardfork for a security problem.

Comment: the reason you can't mark my response as an answer is because it was just a comment. i thought i would let someone try to write a good answer but i figured i would quickly give you a response so you knew the answer :D i am not a good writer but i knew the answer :D

Answer (score 3):

samwellj posted the answer 'hardforks are good for updating the network'. 
The Monero dev's are taking a different stance on hardforks than bitcoin does, but it's a weighted decision where hardforks are announced 6 months beforehand and miners activate hardforks by sagnalling for it.

If I understand correctly, a certain percentage of miners signalling for the hardfork is what activates it. An argument in moneros favor for miner-signalled hard-forks are it's  (potentially) more decentralized mining.  If bitcoin tried that we'd be forked already